# Unable to stop service using AlarmManager in Android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have a code in which alarm manager starts a service. I have to cancel it with the specified time using a second alarm. Not a single solution that I've looked at works. My code is as follows:

```
 void startAtInterval(int fromTime, int fromTimeMinute, int toTime, int toTimeMinute, int id1, int id2) {
    // start alarm

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, fromTime);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, fromTimeMinute);

    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);

    // stop alarm

  AlarmManager alarmMgr1 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent1 = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, toTime);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, toTimeMinute);

    alarmMgr1.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent1);
    stopService(intent);

        alarmMgr1.cancel(alarmIntent1);

}
```

I used `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` and `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`. I also tried to `stopservice` as I show in my code. I'm passing time from a configuration screen. I know it works because first alarm is always fired.

Answer (score 0):

To stop any alarm manager you have to use this:

```
Intent intentS = new Intent(ctx,YourService.class);
            intentS.addCategory("SOMESTRING_AS_TAG");
            PendingIntent senderS = PendingIntent.getService(ctx, NDX, intentS, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            am.cancel(senderS);
            senderS.cancel();

    //and  this
        PendingIntent senderSNew = PendingIntent.getService(ctx, NDX, intentS, 0);
        am.cancel(senderSNew);
        senderSNew.cancel();
```

where `NDX` is the same as started. That is `0` in your case. Or, much better, change your NDX to a some random contant number.

to stop:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,YourService.class);
    intent.addCategory("SOMESTRING_AS_TAG");
    ctx.stopService(intent);
```

Comment: When I use same NDX  in both alarms (start and stop) the first is never fired. I made another try just in case, but it didn't work. But, if i change numbers, first is fired.

Comment: @NachoC. , the first is first. So, will it be cancelled?

Comment: @NachoC. , whtat do you want? stop the service?

Comment: exactly, that is what I need

Answer (score 0):

You should have the second alarm which cancels the service fire a `BroadcastReceiver` which then stops the service.  This will ensure that the alarm will successfully stop the service under any circumstances, such as the app being closed.

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr1 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intentCancelService= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StopServiceReceiver.class);
PendingIntent alarmIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), StopServiceReceiver.REQUEST_CODE, intentCancelService, PendingIntent.GoTestAlarmReceiver);

Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar1.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, toTime);
calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, toTimeMinute);

alarmMgr1.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent1);
```

Then make your `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class GoTestAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 123123;  //whatever code just unique

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, YourServiceClassHere.class);
    context.stopService(i);
    }
}
```

Make sure to declare the receiver in your manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".StopServiceReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:process=":remote" />
```

Comment: Are you sure about PendingIntent.GoTestAlarmReceiver in getBroadcast() method? It is underlined by compiler P.s. i am new to Android and cannot understand what should be placed there

Comment: For now i pasted there PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT